# win32 MapAndLoad doesn't work when i use path with special characters

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a problem when I want to use `MapAndLoad()` with a path which contains special characters, like `ł`, it doesn't work. I read that it takes ASCII characters, so how can I call this function when my path has non-ASCII chars?

```
std::string path = "C:\\Users\\user\\łał\\lib\\native.dll";

if (!MapAndLoad(path.c_str(), nullptr, &LoadedImage, TRUE, TRUE)) {
    fmt_println("MapAndLoad failed");
    return;
}

ImageExportDirectory = (_IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY *)
    ImageDirectoryEntryToData(LoadedImage.MappedAddress,
                              false,
                              IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT, &cDirSize);
if (ImageExportDirectory == nullptr) {
    fmt_println("ImageExportDirectory == nullptr");
    return;
}

dNameRVAs = (DWORD *) ImageRvaToVa(LoadedImage.FileHeader,
                                   LoadedImage.MappedAddress,
                                   ImageExportDirectory->AddressOfNames, nullptr);
for (size_t i = 0; i < ImageExportDirectory->NumberOfNames; i++) {
    sName = (char *) ImageRvaToVa(LoadedImage.FileHeader,
                                  LoadedImage.MappedAddress,
                                  dNameRVAs[i], nullptr);
    fmt_println("{}", sName);
}

UnMapAndLoad(&LoadedImage);
```

I tried to use code which iterate over directories:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATAA findData;
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileA((path + "\\*").c_str(), &findData);
if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    do {
        if (findData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
            fmt_println("dir: {}", findData.cFileName);

            //print as hex
            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(findData.cFileName); ++i) {
                fmt_println("{}", (int) findData.cFileName[i]);
            }
            fmt_println("--------------");
        } else {
//          fmt_println("file: {}", findData.cFileName);
        }
    } while (FindNextFileA(hFind, &findData));
    FindClose(hFind);
}
```

and here's the output:

```
dir: łał ffffffc5ffffff8261ffffffc5ffffff82
-59
-126
97
-59
-126
```

Comment: Try a UTF-8 encoded string. If that doesn't work, try the short path name instead. The `reinterpret_cast` looks suspicious. If we are looking at the actual code, this converts the expression to the same type it already has. What's up with that?

Comment: @IInspectable I tried with UTF-8 encoded string with the same error, also short path doesn't work because it doesn't trim that dir with special characters

Comment: The reinterpret_cast is basically a no-op. Instead of `reinterpret_cast<PCSTR>(path.c_str())` it can just be `path.c_str()` as the first parameter.  It's unclear what encoding MapAndLoad expects.

Comment: @selbie 
WINBOOL IMAGEAPI MapAndLoad(PCSTR ImageName,PCSTR DllPath,PLOADED_IMAGE LoadedImage,WINBOOL DotDll,WINBOOL ReadOnly);

and also
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types

Comment: PCSTR 
A pointer to a constant null-terminated string of 8-bit Windows (ANSI) characters. For more information, see Character Sets Used By Fonts.

Comment: also maybe there is a better way to read exports of library without loading?

Comment: @Kaspek - I suspect its an encoding issue with the string.  Have you tried using FindFirstFileA/FindNextA file on `C:\\users` to identify the correct spelling of that `łał` string in ANSI?

Comment: I don't know what `MapAndLoad` does internally, but maybe a call to [`LoadLibraryExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexw) can be used to load the module as a data file. Also, can you remove the cast and see if the code still compiles?

Comment: @selbie i edited the post with what you requested for

Comment: @IInspectable yeah cast removing doesn't work too, and i don't want to use LoadLibrary because i have 100+ libraries to check about exports

Comment: As shown [in this implementation of `MapAndLoadW`](https://gist.github.com/pavel-a/090cbe4b2aea9a054c55974b7c7be634#file-wc-fixer-cpp-L240) the solution is `GetShortFileNameW()`

Comment: *"cast removing doesn't work"* - What does that mean? Does the code no longer compile without the cast? If so, then that is part of the issue. If the code still compiles without the cast, then leave it away. It doesn't do anything in this case.

Comment: @IInspectable I meant it's compile in both cases, when I remove cast also, but in both cases - it doesn't work if in the path there is a special characters

Comment: As a general rule, Windows APIs that take 8-bit file names use the runtime ANSI character set (unless overridden by`SetFileApisToOEM`). It is not clear what character set the string literal `"C:\\Users\\user\\łał\\lib\\native.dll"` is using for encoding. Inspect the bytes to find out. My guess is that it's not using the same character set as the execution character set.

Comment: What is the special character `ł`? You need to make sure the `ł` character is part of the ASCII standard.

Comment: That's interesting. Given the test code, the character `ł` is encoded as the byte sequence `0xC5` `0x82`. That's UTF-8, meaning the test code uses `CP_UTF8` as the active code page. It's unclear how the test code and the code above relate. Whether you use a string literal (as shown in the code) or query for the pathname at run time makes a meaningful difference: The source character set is relevant for the former but not the latter. Please show a [mcve] so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

`MapAndLoad` is a legacy ANSI-only API that works with strings encoded as [code page encodings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-pages).

You can try to create a app manifest to opt-in for UTF-8 for ANSI APIs as a workaround.

Just create an `<appName>.manifest` near your app exe file:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <assemblyIdentity name="Organization.Division.Name" version="6.0.0.0" />
  <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2019/WindowsSettings"> 
      <activeCodePage>UTF-8</activeCodePage> 
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests#activeCodePage

Comment: As of Windows Version 1903 (May 2019 Update), you can use the ActiveCodePage property in the appxmanifest for packaged apps, or the fusion manifest for unpackaged apps, to force a process to use UTF-8 as the process code page.

|| it's about applications, you sure it would work with dll libraries? because it doesn't create a process

Comment: I believe that dll with inherit code page of a calling process.